# How to set Timer in java for connecting Mysql

Tags: java, multithreading

I am make a small chat application. I develop both front and back end code. I get user information from UI(userName, male, gender) then submit. when click submit button redirect next page UI will show Timer 30 sec (30,29,28, ......., 0) and save data;

user1 submit and user2 submit;

default DB status 'NC' (Not Connected)

At the same time my java code will search any 'W' (waiting) is available in my DB. If available both are connected 30 sec after 30 sec will disconnected else user will change status 'W' to 30 sec.

```
mysql> desc userStatus;
+--------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field  | Type               | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+--------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id     | int                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| user1  | int                | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| user2  | int                | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| status | enum('W','C','NC') | YES  |     | NC                |                                               |
| time   | timestamp          | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.38 sec)
```

user1 ->  Not available status 'W' user will change 'W' for 30 sec after 30 sec automatically disconnected and change status 'NC' (Not Connected). user2 -> In between 30 sec any other person enter (userName, email, gender) and same process Timer start 30 sec in UI then java will search any 'W' in DB. But already user1 is available so user1 and user2 connected and communicate 30 sec.  This process continuely

My problem is how to search 'W' in DB. If available both connected otherwise response will send 'not available';
How to wait 30 sec in java code and if 'W' is available immunity will connect 30 sec;